# "Report Message" Outlook add-in: How does a user request support with determining whether a message is legit?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook

Here's a user story:

*"As a user I receive a message that I feel uncertain about. Is it legit or not? I want to ask somebody for support."*

Is there a way to do implement this via the "Report Message" add-in? Is there another add-in to cover this use-case?

The default options "Junk", "Phishing", "Not Junk" better cover the use-case *"As a user I know this message is Phishing and I want to report it."*

We could train users to report as Phishing even if they are not sure. But then an admin would have to look at every single reported message. I would rather have admins focus on the edge cases, where a users asks for support, than on the much more common case where the user already has determined that it is phishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the "Report Message" add-in might be able to handle this use case, it might not be the best choice. Instead, you might think about introducing a unique feature or add-on designed especially for users who require support and are unsure about a message.

A "Request Support" button or feature that allows users to mark a message as unclear and ask for help from an administrator or designated support team is one possibility. This might come with a form that users can fill out to add details or context to the message.

Another choice would be to give users access to a "Message Verification" add-in that would enable them to submit messages for manual or automated system verification. Once the message has been examined, the add-in might give an update on its validity.

By giving users who are unsure about a message these extra options, you can help them out and free up admins to work on the more complicated cases that need their attention.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do implement this via the "Report Message" add-in?

According to [the official article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-report-message-add-in-b5caa9f1-cdf3-4443-af8c-ff724ea719d2), seems like there's no native option available to implement this into the "Report Message" add-in.

As mentioned in the linked document, you can click "No" at the bottom of that page and leave a comment there asking for an feature improvement.

Answer (score 0):

There are already solutions from multiple vendors in the third party Outlook plugin market that fill this gap. Microsoft usually does not replace these once they exist.  Or they have a solution that is obviously not the same quality so as to not interfere with the third party ecosystem.

It is probably worth noting that the way out of this is measuring when a user actually opens an offending email message instead of deleting it, by sending test messages. This is also the #1 feature of their products. Once users delete instead of open, there are no messages for sysadmins to review. This simple feedback mechanism has proven highly effective. In nearly all organizations, particularly larger organizations, sysadmins do not review email messages.

Comment: I'm aware of phishing simulations. But I don't get the second paragraph: Are you suggesting to tell users to delete phishing emails that made it through the filters instead of reporting them? I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Are you aware of a third-party add-in that plugs into the Microsoft backend for message reporting?